# Is there a way to reset my battle points?

Tags: dota-2

This may seem like an odd question, but after almost 300 hours of playing, I still suck horribly and find myself getting matched up with/against people who are *way* above my head. Both sides will complain of my noobness and say I should delete DOTA, sometimes even going so far as to abandon the match because they apparently find it hopeless to play with me. Needless to say this is frustrating and demotivating.

I would just like to start from scratch again at level 1 so that I can get matched up with/against similarly skilled people.

Comment: Matchmaking is based on a hidden skill rating and is completely distinct from your battle points. Try to find some friendly people to play with who can help you learn.

Comment: lol,you can play perfectly and you will always find someone telling you to delete dota...Welcome to the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can't** simply reset your battle points.
You could make new steam account,but if you already bought some other games on steam that is not a valid solution.

Dota 2 doesn't match you with other players based on your battlepoints or played games at all since it wouldn't be so fair to people just getting started.
Simply put it works primarily on your Win/Lose ratio.
[Here is official detailed matchmaking guide](http://blog.dota2.com/2013/12/matchmaking/) if you want to see exactly how it matches players together.

So resetting your battlepoints isn't some solution,it would last shortly and once again you would get back with the same crowd.
U can usually feel when you get teamed with better players but after some time of  terrible games you should fall back with noobs and win some games.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is NO. You cannot reset your battle points for the same Steam account.

The other part of your question, about being not a good player, is a very common thing which all DOTA beginners experience. I myself have went through this kind of feeling so don't worry, this happens with most players. Remember DOTA has a huge learning curve and 300 hours of gameplay experience is not much if you really want to master the game. I have been playing DotA for more than 3 years on and off and I'm still not 'Dendi'. On my best day, I am an above average player.

Let me ask you one thing. Why do you think some players are pros and others are noob? What is the difference between them? I know so many players who are my friends, who mastered the game in less than 6 months and I also know other friends (whose count is way more than the good ones) who play like crap even after playing regularly for more than 3 years. The individual's skill level comes into play here. Also, doesn't matter how good you are, there will always be someone better than you. So don't get disheartened.

As far as I think, DOTA is about 'presence of mind' more than anything. Your mind is your greatest asset in DOTA. Its all about mind games, though various other factors such as reflexes, map awareness and overall knowledge and experience of the game also counts.

So if there is a player better than you, you should understand and accept it in a positive spirit that he is more skilled than you at this current point of time. See, I am not demotivating you or anyone. But if you want to be better than him, you will have to work hard, practice more (AND MORE) and LEARN as much as you can from other experienced players. The best way to do that is by watching DOTA replays of the teams which you like (good teams like NaVi, E-Home etc.) and of players (good players like Dendi, Puppy etc.) playing heroes which you like. You can find these replays on the internet freely. Try doing that and you will definitely see yourself improving.

Comment: While I appreciate what you're trying to say, the question is only asking about resetting battle points.  Sorry.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Im sorry, but I think you failed to understand WHY he wants to reset his battle points. I just gave him the answer for that. And besides, I seriously could not care less about your down vote. So no need of saying sorry.

Comment: I think your answer *does* cover some of the underlying reasons behind the question, and should not be deleted or anything... but it's just a little hard to follow, and 'practice and get better' just doesn't seem like it has much value to me.